# ImportError: No module named 'requests' but, requests has been installed

Tags: python-requests, python-3.4

I have installed requests on my mac, but the error message says the library does not exist. I have included "import requests" on line one of my Python script. I am using Python 3 for the call because it supports Server Name Indication, which I guess I need for this? Any pointers/help is greatly appreciated!

As you can see, I have installed requests:
Daves-MacBook-Pro:documents Dave$ pip install requests

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Cleaning up...

However when I try to run my script I get this error message:

Daves-MacBook-Pro:documents Dave$ python3 perka_call.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "perka_call.py", line 1, in

```
import requests
```

ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Your `pip` command is showing you have `requests` installed *for Python 2.7*. Not for Python 3.4. Do you have `pip` installed for Python 3.4? Is there a `pip3` command anywhere? Check what version of Python that command works with with `pip3 -V`.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing requests module for Python3. You have installed it for Python2.7
This might do the job.

```
pip install --target='/usr/lib/python3.4/' requests
```

I am assuming you are using python3.4